# Create Multi Segment Cobol copybook file in Mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I need to create a cobol copybook file from incoming JSON. It is a multisegment file. I am facing an issue while creating the multiple segments in the DW.
For the purpose this question I just hardcoded the value as below.

```
DW Code:
%dw 2.0
output application/flatfile schemaPath = "schemas/VP.ffd", structureIdent="MultiSegment"
var fieldDataArray= 0 to 3
fun filterKey(keyName, keyArray) = sizeOf(keyArray filter ((item, index) -> item ~= keyName ))==1
---
{
    vps: {
        vps: [{
            ":USRDSB:-SOURCE": {
                ":USRDSB:-SOURCE": "SOURCE",
                ":USRDSB:-SOURCE-ID ": "MULESOFT"
            },
            ":USRDSB:-HEADER": {
                ":USRDSB:-HEADER": "HEADER",
                ":USRDSB:-TRANSMISSION-ID": "VTY"
            },
            ":USRDSB:-DETAIL-RECORD": payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
                
                ( fieldDataArray map  {
                    ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND": flatten(payload01 pluck $$) match {
                        case k if(filterKey("Option_Set__c",flatten(payload01 pluck $$)) and $$ == 0) -> "019303" as Number 
                        case k if(filterKey("Statement_Message_ID__c",flatten(payload01 pluck $$)) and $$ == 1) -> "014205" as Number
                        case k if(filterKey("CDF23__c",flatten(payload01 pluck $$)) and $$ == 2) -> "008902"  as Number
                        case k if(filterKey("ASC__c",flatten(payload01 pluck $$)) and $$ == 3) -> "011206" as Number
                        else -> "1" as Number

                   }
                   

                }),
                 ":USRDSB:-CARD-NBR": payload01.TSYS_ID__c,
                    ":USRDSB:-CUST-IND": "D",
                    ":USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA": payload01.Statement_Message_ID__c
                
            }
        }]
    }
}

form: COPYBOOK
structures:
- id: 'MultiSegment'
  name: MultiSegment
  data:
  - groupId: 'vps'
    items:
    - groupId: 'vps'
      count: '>1'
      items:
        - { idRef: ':USRDSB:-SOURCE', count: 1 }
        - { idRef: ':USRDSB:-HEADER', count: 1 }
        - { idRef: ':USRDSB:-DETAIL-RECORD', count: '>1' }
  
segments: 
- id: ':USRDSB:-SOURCE'
  values: 
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-COMMENT-IND', type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: 'FILLER1', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-SOURCE', type: String, length: 6, value: 'SOURCE' }
  - { name: 'FILLER2', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-SOURCE-ID ', type: String, length: 8, value: 'MULESOFT' }
- id: ':USRDSB:-HEADER'
  values: 
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-COMMENT-IND', type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: 'FILLER1', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-HEADER', type: String, length: 6, value: 'HEADER' }
  - { name: 'FILLER2', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-TRANSMISSION-ID', type: String, length: 8, value: 'TBC' }
  - { name: 'FILLER3', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
- id: ':USRDSB:-DETAIL-RECORD'
  values: 
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-COMMENT-IND', type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: 'FILLER1', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-FIELD-IND', type: Integer, length: 6, format: { justify: ZEROES, sign: UNSIGNED }}
  - { name: 'FILLER2', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-CARD-NBR', type: String, length: 19 }
  - { name: 'FILLER3', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-CUST-IND', type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: 'FILLER4', usage: U, type: String, length: 1 }
  - { name: ':USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA', type: String, length: 80 }
  - { name: 'FILLER5', usage: U, type: String, length: 9 }
```

Input:

```
[
  {
        "Statement_Message_ID__c": "15673",
        "ActivityDate": "2024-01-02T17:00:00.000Z",
        "Option_Set__c": "801",
        "TSYS_ID__c": "12346849",
        "Id": null,
        "type": "TransactionJournal",
        "ASC__c": "V01",
        "CDF23__c": "1"
    },
    {
        "Statement_Message_ID__c": "15839",
        "ActivityDate": "2024-01-02T17:00:00.000Z",
        "Option_Set__c": "813",
        "TSYS_ID__c": "12347015",
        "Id": null,
        "type": "TransactionJournal",
        "ASC__c": "V01",
        "CDF23__c": "1"
    }
]
```

Expected output:

```
  SOURCE MULESOFT
  HEADER NNNNSCRB
  019303 12346849352
  008902 1234684902  
  011206 12346849V02 
  014205 12346849F0015
  019303 12347015353
  008902 1234701503
  011206 12347015V03
  014205 12347015F0015
```

**Currently, it is creating only one record**

```
  SOURCE MULESOFT
  HEADER SPLNSCRB
  019303 12346849            352
  008902 12346849            02  
  011206 12346849            D 15673  
  014205 12346849            F0015
  019303 12347015            353
  008902 12347015            03
  011206 12347015            V03
  014205 12347015            F0015
```

What am I missing in the dataweave script?

Comment: What is the issue you are having? What is the actual output? Provide the errors if any.

Comment: @aled -  I am getting below error Message  : "com.mulesoft.flatfile.lexical.WriteException - Writer error: not a map list 'Data'
com.mulesoft.flatfile.lexical.WriteException: Writer error: not a map list 'Data'

Comment: @aled the FFD has multiple segments. How to map all the segments in the code?

Comment: Please share an example input.

Comment: @aled I have updated the question. Basically, it is creating one record. But it has to create 4 per object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema seems to be missing a structure. In the structure you can set the detail record to have multiple records so it can receive an array of records. Then the output keys need to match the schema names.

Schema with structure:

```yaml
form: COPYBOOK
structures:
- id: 'main'
  name: Main record
  data:
  - { idRef: ':USRDSB:-SOURCE' }
  - { idRef: ':USRDSB:-HEADER' }
  - { idRef: ':USRDSB:-DETAIL-RECORD', count: '>1' }

segments: 
- id: ':USRDSB:-SOURCE'
...
```

Note that I set the missing value to 'spaces' for better readability. I removed the `structureIdent` setting.

Script:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/flatfile schemaPath = "schemas/schema.ffd" , missingValues="spaces"
---
{
  
    ":USRDSB:-SOURCE": {
        ":USRDSB:-COMMENT-IND": "A"
    },
    ":USRDSB:-HEADER": {
        ":USRDSB:-COMMENT-IND": "B"
    },
    ":USRDSB:-DETAIL-RECORD": payload map ( payload01 , indexOfPayload01 ) -> {
        ":USRDSB:-COMMENT-IND": "1",
        ":USRDSB:-FIELD-IND": 6111 as Number,
        ":USRDSB:-CARD-NBR":"15151515151515151" ,
        ":USRDSB:-CUST-IND": "D",
        ":USRDSB:-FIELD-DATA": "TETETETTETETETETET"
    }
}
```

Input:

```json
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Output:

```
A SOURCE MULESOFT
B HEADER TBC
1 006111 15151515151515151   D TETETETTETETETETET
1 006111 15151515151515151   D TETETETTETETETETET
1 006111 15151515151515151   D TETETETTETETETETET
1 006111 15151515151515151   D TETETETTETETETETET
1 006111 15151515151515151   D TETETETTETETETETET
```

In your application you'll want to replace the fixed values by values coming from the payload.

Comment: I have updated the question. Basically, it is creating one record. But it has to create 4 per object.

Comment: You have edited the question in a way that is a different issue. Questions here should not be changed so significantly that it is a different issue. Either accept the answer for the original question or explain why it was not acceptable. If you want to expand the problem or you used the solution and got into another issue then you should open a new question.

Comment: I understand. I initially accepted the answer. But, site is not allowing me to open a new question. so I reopened

Comment: That's strange but is not  not a reason to edit an existing accepted answer.

Comment: Autogenerated schema in the studio has issues. So, I have to do it manually

Comment: Basically, I need to generate 4 records for each key in the object (ASC__c,CDF23__c,Option_Set__c,Statement_Message_ID__c,). TSYS_ID__c is the parent under which I need to create 4 records.

Comment: You need to open a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256545/discussion-between-veejay-and-aled).